# how to move rows from the begining of a table to the end of it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table:

```
tblRows (RowIndex int identity,  Data int)
```

what is the best way to take X  rows and move it to the end of the table? 
for example , let's say there are 1000 rows in the table, RowIndex is 1-1000.
i want to move first 50 rows to the end, so now RowIndex will be 51-1050.

Should i use Delete and then insert or use update?

The Data Column must be unique , so delete first and then insert is possible.

The order of the row is important.

Comment: ??, like `RowIndex + 50`?, what does `move rows` means here?

Comment: You should definitely Insert *first*, then delete.  Update won't work directly because of the Identity column.

Comment: this is entirely unnecessary. SQL doesn't care about the ordering of rows in the table, and nor should you. Your RowIndex field is an identity field, it's just a unique identifer. Ordering is done when retrieving/displaying data via queries. The order it's stored in does not matter at all. If you want to have your data be _displayed_ in a particular order, consider creating another field called "DisplayOrder" or something, and when you retrieve the data, use that field in the ORDER BY clause of your query.

Comment: Another point - changing the unique identifier of a record, as you're effectively proposing, is a bad idea, because then you can't rely on that identifier as actually identifying the record in question. Once you've given a record a unique identifier, keep it. And as I pointed out in the comment above, use secondary fields to denote things like the order of display.

Answer (score 0):

use insert, then delete.

```
INSERT INTO tblRows(Data)
SELECT Data
FROM MyTable
WHERE RowIndex <= 50
```

then once you have verified the data has been added,

```
DELETE FROM tblRows
WHERE RowIndex <= 50
```

Comment: This does in no way GUARANTEE that the old record #1 will become #1001, or that #2 becomes #1002, etc. Sql Tables are a SET and inherently unordered.

Comment: in that case you could do similar with identity_insert set to off and explicitly calculate the new indexes

Comment: @PeterB, while I don't make any guarantees that 1 will become 1001, etc., it does ensure that the range would change from 1..1000 to 51..1050, which is what was asked for.

Comment: It does not ensure correct range. Putting identity 'jumps' aside, if anyone ever inserts any record into tblRows and the deletes it, new identity value will be greater already. Using `identity_insert` is only way (and only when there will be no conflicts between identity values).

Comment: because Data is unique, first need to delete top 50 then insert that 50 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblRows On;  
with cte as (select top 50 RowIndex, 
                           (SELECT MAX(t.RowIndex) FROM tblRows t) + row_number() 
                           over (order by RowIndex) rn,DATA  from tblRows order by RowIndex)
    INSERT  tblRows (RowIndex, Data)  SELECT RN AS ROWINDEX, DATA  from cte;
;with cte as (select top 50 * FROM tblRows ORDER by RowIndex)
    DELETE cte;
```

To avoid unique constraints you can query out what you want to move to a temp table, then delete rows, then insert from temp table.

```
;with cte as (select top 50 RowIndex, 
                           (SELECT MAX(t.RowIndex) FROM tblRows t) + row_number() 
                           over (order by RowIndex) rn,DATA  from tblRows order by RowIndex)
SELECT * INTO #tblRows_temp FROM cte;           

with cte as (select top 50 * FROM tblRows ORDER by RowIndex)
    DELETE cte;


SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblRows On;  
    INSERT  tblRows (RowIndex, Data)  SELECT RN AS ROWINDEX, DATA  from #tblRows_temp;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tblRows Off;  

DROP TABLE #tblRows_temp;
```

Comment: because Data is unique, first need to delete top 50  then insert that 50 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i came up with this:
Added a column RowOrder int so the table is now look like this:

```
tblRows (RowIndex int identity,  Data int,RowOrder int)
```

Updated  the RowOrder  from 1 to 1000:

```
update tblRows 
set RowOrder = rn
from (
       select RowOrder,
              row_number() over(order by (select RowIndex)) as rn
       from tblRows 

     ) tblRows
```

Created a temp table that will hold the rows i want to move:

```
DECLARE @TempRows TABLE (RowOrder int,Data int)    

INSERT INTO @TempRows(RowOrder,Data )
SELECT TOP (50) RowOrder,Data 
FROM tblRows 
ORDER BY RowOrder

-- delete rows
DELETE 
FROM  tblRows 
WHERE RowOrder BETWEEN 1 AND 50

-- add rows to the end of the table
INSERT INTO tblRows (RowOrder,Data )
SELECT RowOrder, Data 
FROM @TempRows 
ORDER BY RowOrder

-- update row order
UPDATE RowOrder
SET RowOrder = rn
FROM(
    SELECT RowOrder, row_number() over(order by (select RowIndex)) as rn
    FROM RowOrder    
    ) RowOrder
```

I'd love to know if there are other more elegant solution.

Comment: this still destroys the unique identifers for the records (they will get a new RowIndex value, which means anything else in another table or application that references that data item will now have an invalid reference) See my answer for a better solution using the same RowOrder column

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't care about the ordering of rows in the table, and nor should you. Your RowIndex field is an identity field, it's just a unique identifier. Ordering is done when retrieving/displaying data via queries. The order it's stored in does not matter at all. And changing the unique identifier of a record is bad for consistency, and could break relationships between that data item and other records held elsewhere (in your DB or other applications) which hold a reference to it.

To solve this, you could for instance add an integer column called RowOrder, and order your data by that instead of RowIndex when you write queries. Initially populate this new column with the same value as the RowIndex for each row.

Then, you mentioned you want to move the first 50 records to the end of the list. So you simply find out the current maximum value of RowOrder, and then (assuming no-one else is adding records to the table at the same time), increment the RowOrder value of the first 50 records by that amount:

```
DECLARE @MaxRowOrder int
SELECT @MaxRowOrder = MAX(RowOrder) FROM tblRows

UPDATE tblRows SET RowOrder = RowOrder + @MaxRowOrder WHERE RowOrder <= 50
```

If you really wanted to be neat, you could write another bit of SQL to substract 50 from all the RowOrder values, so that they start at 1 again.

```
UPDATE tblRows SET RowOrder = (RowOrder - 50)
```

To retrieve your rows in the intended order, it's simple:

```
SELECT * FROM tblRows ORDER BY RowOrder
```